# What is a str file with respect to TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

There are several uses of the isSTRFile function in the source code for the TypeScript compiler, but no clue as to what a .str file is. Anders makes reference to 'stir files' in his intro to TypeScript video rather than .ts files. Does anyone know what they are, or were? My best guess is that .str stands for 'structure file' and was the precursor to .d.ts files - in which case .str files are obsolete. Can any one shed any light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the product was under development, it had a different code name, and an extension to go along with that code name.  When an actual product name was chosen, the extension was updated accordingly.

So it's just a historical remnant in the code.  It has no semantic meaning.

Comment: Ah right - TypeScript's code name was Strada. That makes sense. Thanks.